# Recover specific files from deleted EXT4 partition

Tags: files, filesystems, data-recovery, ext4

Is there any way to recover a few specific files from a deleted EXT4 partition.  I deleted all partitions on my 480GB SSD.  Afterwards, I created a 200 GB NTFS partition (which is mostly empty) and I have about 280 GB still unpartitioned.

I didn't do a "wipe" (or whatever it's called), so it was a quick deletion process.

I'm currently only running Windows (on a completely different SSD), but I would be happy to boot up a Linux Live CD if needed.

I was going to throw Linux on that unpartitioned 280GB but now I don't want to touch it until I figure out if I can recover that data.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use System rescue CD as a live cd

https://www.system-rescue-cd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage you'll find the photoRec software in it, to recover lost data.

You can also use the soft directly from windows:

www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec

Here some details on how to use photoRec
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step

PS: Don't be to focus on the name of the software it does recover more than only photos

Comment: Sorry about the late response. I actually combined your solution with Vikelidis's solution (tough deciding who to mark as the answer).  Basically I tried TestDisk and it wasn't working from my booted instance, but I used the version of TestDisk off the System Rescue CD live instance, and I got everything I needed!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [testDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to recover the partition table (if you are lucky enough). If this is done successfully  you will have full access in your files.

Comment: Oh my goodness THANK YOU! I just overwrote a drive without taking a backup (last time I did that I was a teenager...) and testdisk combined with fsck was able to recover my files. THANK YOU!